# Loading a list of strings in to JS from Flask

Tags: python, flask

I've been working on a project using MySQL and Python alongside flask, and part of my code requires javascript it works perfectly with all my other lists which are passed to the page through flask. But this list consists of strings such as "Candles 15", "Armour 2" and "Dark Sword" while the other lists only consist of primary keys and foreign keys. Please see the code below:

```js
itemnames = JSON.parse("{{itemnames|tojson}}")
```

The error given is:

```
missing ) after argument list
```

Comment: Have you tried: `itemnames = JSON.parse("{{itemnames|safe}}")` ?

Comment: @nadiantara-i-wayan yes I just tried it and no luck sadly!